# Is there any way to reduce the fraction $2^x/x$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

so that the numerator doesn't rise so rapidly? In other words, can a factor y of $2^x$ where $y\cdot x = 2^x$ be represented algebraicly in terms of $x$? If not, why not? This may help develop an idea about the computational complexity of finding prime numbers.
Thanks!

Comment: Note that $2^x$ is exponential and grows faster more than any polynomial ($x^a = o(2^x)$)

Answer (score 1):

No. Any odd number has no factor two, but the numerator still has only factors two. Therefore the fraction is irreducible for all odd $x$.